# what options to use with gcc to get maximum security checks?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

I am using VC++ 2010 at work and gcc 4.7 at home for C,C++ programming. I noticed that compiler options for checking subtle errors like stack overflow,heap corruption, use of uninitialized variables etc. are by default on in vc++ but not in gcc. While going through the gcc manual I found options like '-fstack-protector' to check stack overflow/corruption.
Can I get a list of all such options and some tips to get all the help I can get from gcc as I get in vc++?
thanks.

Comment: For C: `-std=c89` or `std=c99` or `-std=c11`; for C++: `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++03` or `-std=c++11`. In addition: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly looking for [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Listing few of them from the site:-

> **-fmax-errors=n**
>
> Limits the maximum number of error messages to n, at which point GCC
>   bails out rather than attempting to continue processing the source
>   code. If n is 0 (the default), there is no limit on the number of
>   error messages produced. If -Wfatal-errors is also specified, then
>   -Wfatal-errors takes precedence over this option.
>
> **-Wall**
>
> This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users
>   consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
>   prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. This also
>   enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect
>   Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.
>   -Wall turns on the following warning flags:
>
> ```
>       -Waddress   
>       -Warray-bounds (only with -O2)  
>       -Wc++11-compat  
>       -Wchar-subscripts  
>       -Wenum-compare (in C/ObjC; this is on by default in C++) 
>       -Wimplicit-int (C and Objective-C only) 
>       -Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C only) 
>       -Wcomment  
>       -Wformat   
>       -Wmain (only for C/ObjC and unless -ffreestanding)  
>       -Wmaybe-uninitialized 
>       -Wmissing-braces (only for C/ObjC) 
>       -Wnonnull  
>       -Wparentheses  
>       -Wpointer-sign  
>       -Wreorder   
>       -Wreturn-type  
>       -Wsequence-point  
>       -Wsign-compare (only in C++)  
>       -Wstrict-aliasing  
>       -Wstrict-overflow=1  
>       -Wswitch  
>       -Wtrigraphs  
>       -Wuninitialized  
>       -Wunknown-pragmas  
>       -Wunused-function  
>       -Wunused-label     
>       -Wunused-value     
>       -Wunused-variable  
>       -Wvolatile-register-var 
>        Note that some warning flags are not implied by -Wall. Some of them warn about constructions that users generally do not consider
> ```
>
> questionable, but which occasionally you might wish to check for;
>   others warn about constructions that are necessary or hard to avoid in
>   some cases, and there is no simple way to modify the code to suppress
>   the warning. Some of them are enabled by -Wextra but many of them must
>   be enabled individually.

Answer (score 0):

try `lint` tool and `gcc -Wall` option